# Problema con intervalo dependiente en carousel con imagenes y videos auto reproducibles bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

estoy intentando crear un carousel con autoplay en con imagenes y videos con bootstrap 4, jquery y html por lo que tengo el siguiente codigo:

en el jquery trato de verificar el elemento que se muestra y el siguiende segun su tipo actualizar el intervalo del slide, al parecer no encuentra el selector pero al usarlo de diferente orden reprodice el video pero ya no cambia el slide.

la idea es tener 5 slides cuando sea imagen tener un intervalo de 5 segundos y luego cuando sea video tener el intervalo correspondiente a la duracion del video y que se reproduzca.

Muchas Gracias por los comentarios...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

            let allVids  = $("#myCarousel").find('.carousel-item.video');
            const carousel = $("#myCarousel");
    
            function setCarouselInterval(interval) {
                carousel.carousel('dispose');
                carousel.carousel({
                    interval: interval
                });
                carousel.carousel('cycle');
            }

            setInterval(function() {
                $('.carousel').carousel('next');
            }, 50000);
    
            allVids.each(function(index, el) {
            if (index !== 0) {
                if ($(this).is('video')) {
                    $(this).find('video')[0].pause();
                }
            }
            });
    
            $("#myCarousel").on('slide.bs.carousel', function(ev) {
                // debugger;
                let slides       = $(this).find('.carousel-item');
                let currentSlide = slides[ev.from];
                let nextSlide    = slides[ev.to];
    
                let currentElement = currentSlide.querySelector('img, video');
                let nextElement    = nextSlide.querySelector('img, video');
    
                if (currentElement.tagName === 'VIDEO') {
                    let currentVideo = currentElement;
                    currentVideo.pause();
                    currentVideo.currentTime = 0;
                }
    
                if (nextElement.tagName === 'VIDEO') {
                    // debugger;
                    let nextVideo = nextElement;
                    let time      = nextVideo.duration;
                    let interval  = time * 1000;
                    nextVideo.play();
                    setCarouselInterval(interval);
                    
                } else {

                    let intervalAux = 5000;
                    setCarouselInterval(intervalAux);
                }
    
            });
        });
```

```css
 #myCarousel {
        max-width: 960px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .carousel-control-next, .carousel-control-prev {
            width: 9% !important;
        }

        .carousel-inner {
        background: #FFF;
        }

        .carousel-indicators {
        bottom: -13px !important;
        }

        .carousel-item {
        padding-bottom: 25px;
        }

        video {
        width: 100%;
        }

        .carousel-item .active, video {
            background-color: #FFF
        }

        .carousel-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-3qaqj0lc6sV/qpzrc1N5DC6i1VRn/HyX4qdPaiEFbn54VjQBEU341pvjz7Dv3n6P" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-SI27wrMjH3ZZ89r4o+fGIJtnzkAnFs3E4qz9DIYioCQ5l9Rd/7UAa8DHcaL8jkWt" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>test</title>
    
</head>
<body>
 <div class="carousel-container">

        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-bs-ride="true">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/vector-gratis/fondo-galaxia-dibujos-animados_52683-63638.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." width="961" height="664">
                </div>

                
              <div class="carousel-item video">
                <video controls class="myvid" id="player2" width="961" height="664">
                      <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                      </video>
              </div>
          
              <div class="carousel-item video">
                <video controls class="myvid" id="player2" width="961" height="664" data-interval="16000">
                      <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                      </video>
              </div>
            </div>
          
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Vorige</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Volgende</span>
            </a>
          </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: 1. ¿Está bien tu código? Dice `(document)` en lugar de `$(document)`. 2. ¿Es Bootstrap 4 o 5? Hay diferencias grandes entre una y otra versión, especialmente porque en la v5 se elimina la dependencia de jQuery.

Comment: 3. ¿Qué valores tienen `currentSlide` y `nextSlide` en consola?

Comment: @padaleiana Gracias. 1. si es $(document) no seleccione al copiar el codigo, 2 es Bootstrap 4, 3. ``` currentSlide <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img src="http://localhost/path/storage/img/upload/ilnp0oaZKd00ad8hVGuMyJlFbelLlJSsOtZ7hRl4.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." width="961" height="664">
                    </div> ```

Comment: y nextSlide ``` nextSlide <div class="carousel-item video" data-interval="425087">
                        <video controls="" autoplay="" loop="" muted="" class="myvid" id="player" width="961" height="664">
                            <source src="http://localhost/path/storage/video/upload/NmAE04YOvgPu7xjxdkyJOBRlMBe4bHVxEBNzhqo4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        </video>
                    </div>```

Comment: @padaleiana muchas gracias, ya lo edite